# Подключение файлов в PHP

Tags: php, include, require

Интересует следующий вопрос. 
Есть файл с функциями main_menu.php
с адресом `site/function/main_menu.php` 
И второй файл index.php 
с адресом `site/root/phone/index.php`

Я хочу в файле index.php подключить функцию, но на require_once('/function/main_menu.php'); и вызов функции интерпретатор отвечает отказом в доступе. Подскажите как правильно реализовать?

Comment: текст ошибки приведите, и каталоги верно указывайте при подключении файлов `require_once('./../../../function/main_menu.php');`

Comment: Warning: require_once(W:\domains\taskmanager\site\root\iphone): failed to open stream: Permission denied in W:\domains\taskmanager\site\root\iphone\index.php on line 2 

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.;w:/modules/php/PHP-7.2-x64;w:/modules/php/PHP-7.2-x64/PEAR/pear') in W:\domains\taskmanager\site\root\iphone\index.php on line 2

Comment: **W:\domains\taskmanager\site\root\iphone** это что за файл такой вы подключаете?

Comment: вот в него нужно подключить main_menu.php

Comment: я вам уже( в первом комментарии) написал как нужно записывать относительный путь, сейчас вы пытаетесь папку открыть как файл, и законно получаете ошибку, или правильно стройте относительный путь или полный путь **'./' - текущий каталог**, **'../' - на каталог выше(родительский каталог)**

Comment: понял, благодарю вас за информацию